# How to stop my timer once all my files are populated in the grid view

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

How can i stop my timer function when i am done with my population of files from different folder to the grid view.
I am successfully taking all the files from four different folder location's and i am showing them in grid view. but **i don't know when to stop the timer. My timer is running all the time. How can i stop this**.

My code snippet:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool authenticated = true;
            if (authenticated == UserInCustomRole(strVal))// && (authenticated &= UserInSystemRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)))
            {
                this.button3.Visible = true;
                this.button2.Visible = false;
                timer1.Start();
                filter_table1();
            }

            if (authenticated == UserInCustomRole(strVal1))// && (authenticated &= UserInSystemRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)))
            {//
                this.button3.Visible = false;
                this.button2.Visible = true;
                timer1.Start();
                filter_table();
            }

        }  

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Draft Path"].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Blue };
            dataGridView1.Columns["Draft Path"].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            dataGridView1.Columns["Draft Path"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;

            dataGridView1.Columns["Drawing Path"].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            dataGridView1.Columns["Drawing Path"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Release Path"].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Blue };
            dataGridView1.Columns["Release Path"].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            dataGridView1.Columns["Release Path"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns["Archive"].Visible = false;
      //  backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        //this.Opacity = 100;
        bool authenticated = true;
        string textboxGroupName1 = ini.ReadValue("Action", "Fabricator");
        if (authenticated == UserInCustomRole(textboxGroupName1))
        {
            dt.Columns["Drawing Number"].ReadOnly = true;
            dt.Columns["Drawing Path"].ReadOnly = true;
            dt.Columns["Release Path"].ReadOnly = true;
            dt.Columns["Draft Path"].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns["Error"].Visible = false;
            //dataGridView1.Columns["Archive"].Visible = true;   //making archive visible to the fabricator

        }

        DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        int rowCount = dataGridView1.BindingContext[dt].Count;
        label1_status.Text = "Records Found: " + (rowCount).ToString();
         }
    }
```

Comment: `Stacy Keb` why do you need a timer for this ..any particular reason..

Comment: @DJKRAZE please see the updated: codes.. i am using timer for that particular reason

Comment: @Steve i know the code to stop timer. But i am confused where i should give it.. i mean how can `know that my all files from different folders are loaded to the gird view`

Comment: It's more likely that whatever you're doing, you should do it without the timer. E.g. if you want to update the UI periodically based on the result of the `filter_table()` and `filter_table1()` methods, then it would be better to design that worker code so that it can explicitly update the UI as it progresses and/or completes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i dont want to update the result periodically.. i just need to run this for very first time.. while loading the form. based on the user it loads form

Comment: @PeterDuniho `filter_table` and `filter_table1`. these are the two function which lodes my files to the grid view. If you would to see my funtion please find it here>> http://pastie.org/9756868

Comment: "i dont want to update the result periodically" -- then you _definitely_ don't want to use a timer. The code in your `Tick` event handler is odd anyway, as the only uncommented lines in the loop don't use the loop variable, nor change in any way during the loop. Seems those should just be executed once. It looks to me as though you should be loading the data asynchronously (which you're not right now) and then do the stuff in your event handler simply by executing it after the loading is completed instead.

Comment: You should use a BackgroundWorker and its ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add information to your question, and please don't use links to external web sites or even other StackOverflow pages in your question. The question should be entirely self-contained. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterDuniho i am so sorry about that..

Comment: @Steve i am using already BackgroundWorker and its ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted for my splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bound your data to your grid you could do it like this:

```
private _bindingCompleted = false;
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    _bindingCompleted = true;
    // You could also stop timer here if it suits your needs
}
```

And then inside your TimerTick event check if binding is complete:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_bindingCompleted)
        timer1.Stop();

    // Rest of your code
}
```